# Retrieving the password from a secret key

Tags: encryption

I generated a secret key using the algorithm "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" and PBEKeySpec. Is there anyway to get the password, if I have the secret key, the salt and the iterations?

-edit-
I generated the secret key in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean getting the password PT from a hashed value, then I don't think it is possible, as it destroys one of the important reason of the hash function.

Still I think if you post the question in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ you might get great answers as this can be best explained by crypto experts.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post my question there instead. Just off the top of your head, do you know any type of encryption I could use that would require a salt and iterations, but I can reverse it to get the password for later use?

Comment: Hashing functions such as SHA1, SHA256, MD5, etc are what might be called one way encryptions, and have a lot of applications. If you would like to decrypt, then you could have a look at AES which is an encryption algorithm and implementations of AES that make it secure such as CBC(Cipher Block Chaining) which takes a random IV(can be considered salt) and a secret key to encrypt data that can be decrypted. If you are going to send the encrypted data over network, you could have a look at authenticated encryption at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption